# Dock Intellihide

Tags: macos, dock

Is there any way to get the dock to use "intellihide" (this is a carry over from various docks in the linux world). Basically that means that the dock is always visible if no windows are in its space, but if a window gets too close, the dock reverts to autohide type behavior. I can only find "autohide" and always visible. I would prefer something as I described.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have developed an application (mainly using AppleScript) that does this, or at least very close to what you want: https://github.com/gjherbiet/DockIntellihide.app

Comment: This method no longer works in El Capitan; the UIScripting flag refuses to be switched. Not sure if SIP or just removed entirely.

Answer (score 2):

No. I don't believe that this is supported by Apple at this time.

Sorry for the pessimistic answer, but to my knowledge it's true.

There may be ways to run Docky or the like through macports or fink.

Comment: But there's no way to remove the default dock correct? So using Docky or something else would leave you running two separate docks with different behavior. In addtion, I just did a quick check and docky (or awn) doesn't exist in the macports or fink repos. I think your first part is correct. Basically: "Impossible"

Comment: If you really want to get rid of the dock, you could use `sudo service [com.apple.dock or something like that]`, I think.